# Is it possible to use live-templates as file templates?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm

In the intellij products I'm very fond of the live-templates. I wonder if it is possible to use the same syntax for file templates, e.g. formatting a variable to snake- or camel-camese, defining a starting cursor position and so on.

Comment: Exactly the same -- no. File Templates use Apache Velocity template language. It allows some Java(?) simple methods to be run on variables (e.g. `#set($class_start = $class.substring(0,1).toUpperCase())`) -- maybe more complex will work as well.

Comment: @LazOne: Very helpful! Especially the hint that they're using the Apache velocity template language. If you post this as an answer, I would accept that.

Comment: Any ideas about how to define the starting cursor position? Every time, I create a new Java Class, the cursor position is at the end of the class name. I have to press keys to get inside the body of the class.

Comment: @Rounak Live Templates are now possible in File Templates (see update) -- if you do not use any file template variables you could potentially use `$END$` live template there(not tested myself).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>Unfortunately you cannot use the same functions/macros available in Live Templates in File Templates.</s>

File Templates use [Apache Velocity template language](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html). It allows some Java(?) simple methods to be run on variables (e.g. `#set($class_start = $class.substring(0,1).toUpperCase())`). Quite possible that more complex methods will work as well.

---

**UPDATE (2017/01/13):**

As of **2016.1** (or perhaps 2016.2) version it's now possible to use some Live Templates in File Templates as well (by checking `Enable Live Templates` checkbox for that File template). I'm not 100% sure if it will do the requested here thing (not tested myself).

Syntax example: `#[[ $MY_VARIABLE$ $END$ ]]#`

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/file-and-code-templates-2.html

Comment: How do you use the LIve Template expressions?   That is how do you associate an expression with a Live variable inside the Velocity template?   Is that possible?