# How to convert $SELECTION$ to snake case(for example) using live templates?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, live-templates

How to convert selected code to snake case for example (or camel case or something other standart expression from live template variable options)

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/edit-template-variables-dialog.html#predefined_functions . I have no clue how it will work if selection will be a few lines of text .. as such transformations meant to work on function/variable names... Live Templates manual: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm

Comment: I want to use it for refactoring function name. Inserting getters and setters with ALT+INSERT generates function names in camel case but I need them in snake case.

Comment: 1) I'm not sure that such Live Template transformation will work in that context ("File and Code Templates" .. which is powered by Velocity) 2) I do not see how `$SELECTION$` can be used here at all. If anything -- you would have to work with `${NAME}` variable .. but it's Velocity variable and not live template one... If anything #2 -- look at Velocity functionality (native Java string functions in particular) -- they *may* work. For example (just to have general idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26428368/783119) -- it *may* work in Generate Code context as well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer was provided in [this comment on the JetBrains forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203385124-Convert-selected-code-to-camel-case-using-live-templates-?page=1#community_comment_204002590)

> There is "String Manipulation" plugin that lets you to convert the
>   case     of selected text via the right click menu or via custom
>   shortcuts assigned at Settings/Preferences > Keymap.
>
> You can install the plugin via Settings/Preferences > Plugins > Browse
>   repositories.

Comment: Does this allow you to do it via live templates though? or is it now a 2 part process?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach it allows you to set a hotkey for this operation, so you can select text and do ctrl+alt+shift+s (in my case) and it will convert the selected text.

Comment: Very sophisticated plugin, impressive